# Judge whether a set of points $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ are on a hyperbola

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

The general equation for a hyperbola is
$$
A x^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0,
$$
and we would need at least $5$ distinct points to uniquely determine a hyperbola. My question is given a set of points $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ (especially for $n>5$), is there a convenient way to judge whether these points are on the same hyperbola?

Comment: Actually, $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F$ is the general equation for conic sections, which include hyperbola, parabola, ellipse, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this answers the question.
An equivalent condition is that the rank of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^2 & x_1y_1 & y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots 
\\
x_n^2 & x_ny_n & y_n^2 & x_n & y_n & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
should be $\leq 5$. If the rank is exactly $5$ the quadric (hyperbola) is unique.

Comment: Actually, $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F$ is the equation for conic sections, which include hyperbola, parabola, ellipse, etc. It seems that the rank condition is not sufficient to judge whether the points are on a hyperbola; they may be on an ellipse.

Comment: OK you are right (indeed I wrote quadric).
It is an hyperbola if and only if $B^2-4AC>0$. Maybe it translates into some condition on the $x_i,y_i$, but the easiest criterion I see is to check whether the rank is $5$ or less. If not, they are not on a conic, hence not on an hyperbola, otherwise check the right null-space of that matrix to see if it contains a vector $(A,B,C,D,E,F)^\top$ with $B^2-4AC>0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a reasonable procedure.